# How do I control the execution order of scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, html-parsing, p5.js

I'm making a small browser game involving p5.js. My HTML is basically this:

```html
<!-- ... -->
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/various/other/scripts.js"></script>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sketch.js"></script>
</body>
<!-- ... -->
```

Most of the time this setup works. However, sometimes (when I first load the page in the browser), I get errors like `ReferenceError: p5 is not defined` from `p5.sound.min.js` and `ReferenceError: loadSound is not defined` from `sketch.js`. When I refresh the page things work fine again, until I close the browser window.

This looks to me like the scripts are executed out of order, because those are the kinds of errors that would be happening if a script was run without its prerequisites having been run. (`sketch.js` requires `p5.sound.min.js` requires `p5.js`.) The order in which I placed them in the HTML is the order in which I want them to run.

I know about `async` and `defer` which affect the way the browser loads and executes JavaScript, and I've tried the latter. However:

- adding `defer` to all `<script>` tags seems to change nothing.
- without `async` or `defer` (like above), wouldn't the execution order *already* be guaranteed and correct?

Is there something else I need to keep in mind?

Answer (score 1):

As always, right after posting the question you find a new trail leading to the solution.

Apparently this has nothing to do with JS execution order, but [a bug in Firefox that prevents local files from loading if they end in '.min.js'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Source_map_errors#NetworkError_when_attempting_to_fetch_resource). I think the workaround for now is to load p5 from a CDN, or change the filename to not include `min`.